# Взаимодействие с изображением на View

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, uwp

На `View` есть несколько `Image`их можно ресайзить двигать и вращать
Вот `Xaml`код `View`:

```
<Image Width="525"
               Height="331"                  
               Canvas.Top="-199"
               Canvas.Left="-361"
               x:Name="CollageImg1"
               ManipulationMode="All"
               Source="{Binding CollageImg1}"
               RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5"  
               ManipulationDelta="CollageImgage1_Manipulation">//
            <Image.RenderTransform>
                <CompositeTransform></CompositeTransform>
            </Image.RenderTransform>
        </Image>
```

Метод в кодбихайнд для взаимодействия

```
 private void OnDrag(object sender, ManipulationDeltaRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ImageManipulator.Manipulation(e, CollageImg1);
    }
```

Который вызывает общий метод для взаимодействия с картинками

```
 public static void Manipulation(ManipulationDeltaRoutedEventArgs e, Image xamlimage)
    {
        CompositeTransform ct = (CompositeTransform)xamlimage.RenderTransform;
        ct.ScaleX *= e.Delta.Scale;
        ct.ScaleY *= e.Delta.Scale;
        ct.TranslateX += e.Delta.Translation.X;
        ct.TranslateY += e.Delta.Translation.Y;
        ct.Rotation += Math.PI * e.Delta.Rotation;
    }
```

Вопрос в том как можно вынести это из кодбихайнд? `Command` не работает для `Image`. Что нужно использовать?

```
public ICommand ManipulationCommand => _manipulateCommand ?? (_manipulateCommand = new CommandHandler(() => OnDrag(), _canExecuteManipulate));
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать Behaviors.

```
<i:Interaction.Behaviors>
    <core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="Tapped">
        <core:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding Любая_команда}"/>
   </core:EventTriggerBehavior>
</i:Interaction.Behaviors>
```

Comment: А что нужно передать в параметрах к моему методу?  И в `Xaml` нужно параметры указывать или только в классе?

Comment: `<core:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding Любая_команда}"
CommandParameter="то_что_хотите_передать_в_метод. "/>` 
Если ничего не передавать, то передается стандартный EventArgs события

Comment: И, кстати, вместо Tapped подставьте нужное событие, на которое должна срабатывать команда.

Comment: Я имел ввиду сюда как передать?http://joxi.ru/Dr83OBecl5DOA6

Comment: Через типизированные команды. В призме это выглядит так:
`DelegateCommand<object>((obj) => { код });` 
Сделайте по образу и подобию. Посмотрите что приходит в object и переделайте под себя.

Answer (score 1):

1. Добавляете `xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"`
2. Используете `EventTrigger`:

   ```
    <Image Width="525"
          Height="331"                  
          Canvas.Top="-199"
          Canvas.Left="-361"
          x:Name="CollageImg1"
          ManipulationMode="All"
          Source="{Binding CollageImg1}"
          RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5"                
       <Image.RenderTransform>
           <CompositeTransform></CompositeTransform>
       </Image.RenderTransform>
       <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                   <i:EventTrigger EventName="ManipulationDelta">
                       <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding }"/>
                   </i:EventTrigger>
       </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    </Image>
   ```

Comment: Using прописал, но после `i` все красное и предлагает подключить `Behavior` от Microsoft

Comment: Это нужно добавлять в xaml в самом верху

Comment: Да, строка даже подсветилась, что используется. Но http://joxi.ru/V2V5g9kIWJ4Rmv

Comment: В таком случае ничего не нужно добавлять) код работает? Привязка проходит?

Comment: Нет, тогда он `Triggers` не видит, `EventName` и `InvokeCommandAction`

Comment: покажите весь код как вы добавили изменения

Comment: Первый `Image` это способ, который предложил Make Makeluv, а ниже тот что Вы http://joxi.ru/l2ZLQ98cZW1yrJ

Comment: вы вызываете `InvokeCommandAction` через `core` сделайте также же через `interactivity`. или даже в таком случае не видит? да, неплохо бы полный скрин где видно как вы прописывали пространства имен

Comment: Не работает даже так http://joxi.ru/Y2LeE9LsGJPDA6 Вот Using, но он не используется в данном случае так как вместо `i` использую `interactivity`http://joxi.ru/DmBJ0BeTBZaKmP

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42866/discussion-between-s-kos-and-smile).

Comment: Triggers используются в WPF, в UWP этого нет.

Comment: Теперь понятно почему у автора не работает мой вариант. Хотя в метках стоит и wpf и uwp